# Awesomium multithreading c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, awesomium

So I'm trying to figure out a way to run 2 or more processes of Webview at the same time? I saw that I could accomplish this with multithreading but Awesomium dosen't support this and it just gives me an error:

```
Awesomium.Core.AweInvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'
```

How can I do this?

my code:

first class:

```
secondclass sclass = new secondclass();
Thread nakedCPH = new Thread(() => sclass.run(name));
nakedCPH.Start();
```

second class:

```
internal ThreadStart runNakedCPH(string v)
{
    MessageBox.Show(v);
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Thread nakedCPH = new Thread(() =>
{
    secondclass sclass = new secondclass();
    sclass.run(name);
});
nakedCPH.Start();
```

The problem you'll get is if the `MessageBox.Show(v);` is running on this new thread. It'll fail because you can only call UI functions on the UI-thread.